# Text distortion in subview

Tags: ios, drawing, uilabel, subview, distortion

I am drawing various characters in iOS using the NSAttributedString drawAtPoint: method, but they seem to be rendered at a lower quality than expected. I thought this may be because of drawing between pixels but a UILabel in the view shows identical distortion.

I have attached a comparison of the drawn characters, a label in the view and a label in the superview to illustrate the problem. Any hep would be much appreciated.

Ben

[image: Text distortion]

Comment: How are you displaying the text in the labels - using the same attributed string method ?

Comment: No the labels are just using a string literal.

Comment: Mmm - there's something odd going on here. Is there anything different about your current view ?

Comment: The only difference that i can tell is that the superview returns YES to canBecomeFirstResponder and canResignFirstResponder